# Plot selected rows with the average and standard deviation (GNUPlot)

Tags: select, row, gnuplot, average, standard-deviation

I have a csv file with experiment results that goes like this:

```
64  4   8   1   1   2   1   ttt 62391   4055430 333 0.0001  10  161 108 288 0
64  4   8   1   1   2   1   ttt 60966   3962810 322 0.0001  10  164 112 295 0
64  4   8   1   1   2   1   ttt 61530   3999475 325 0.0001  10  162 112 291 0
64  4   8   1   1   2   1   ttt 61430   4054428 332 0.0001  10  158 110 286 0
64  4   8   1   1   2   1   ttt 63891   4152938 339 0.0001  9   149 109 274 0
64  4   32  1   1   2   1   ttt 63699   4204182 345 0.0001  4   43  179 240 0
64  4   32  1   1   2   1   ttt 63326   4116218 336 0.0001  4   45  183 248 0
64  4   32  1   1   2   1   ttt 62654   4135211 340 0.0001  4   48  178 248 0
64  4   32  1   1   2   1   ttt 63192   4107506 339 0.0001  4   49  175 245 0
64  4   32  1   1   2   1   ttt 62707   4138666 345 0.0001  4   46  179 245 0
64  4   64  1   1   2   1   ttt 60968   3962929 323 0.0001  4   46  191 256 0
64  4   64  1   1   2   1   ttt 58765   3819787 305 0.0001  4   50  196 267 0
64  4   64  1   1   2   1   ttt 58946   3831499 308 0.0001  5   52  187 260 0
64  4   64  1   1   2   1   ttt 60646   3942047 321 0.0001  4   47  187 254 0
64  4   64  1   1   2   1   ttt 59723   3882044 311 0.0001  4   46  201 269 0
64  8   8   1   1   2   1   ttt 63414   4185382 382 0.0001  33  517 109 643 0
64  8   8   1   1   2   1   ttt 62429   4057899 372 0.0001  33  538 110 667 0
64  8   8   1   1   2   1   ttt 60622   3940452 384 0.0001  33  556 115 689 0
64  8   8   1   1   2   1   ttt 64433   4188192 369 0.0001  33  519 110 644 0
```

My goal is to be able to plot various combinations (choose which, in different charts) of the columns before the "ttt", with the average and standard deviation of the columns (choose which) after "ttt" (by grouping them by the before "ttt" columns).

Is this possible in GNUPlot and if yes how? If not, do you have any alternate suggestions regarding my problem?

Comment: Please clarify: do you mean for example select row N based on some combination of columns 1-7 and then plot the average of columns 14 15 16 in that same row? Or do you mean plot the average of column 13 taken over all columns with column 2 == 8? Or something else?

Comment: The second one. Something like SELECT $3, AVERAGE($9), STD_DEV($9) WHERE $2 = 4 GROUP BY $3, in a (extremely) loose sql format.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want to plot.  Where does the x coordinate come from?  What y coordinate[s] do you want to plot at that x?

Comment: x is taken from the before columns, $3 in the above example. y is the average and standard deviation of the grouped by after columns, AVERAGE($9), STD_DEV($9) (as the error) in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a completely revised and more general version.

Since you want to filter by 3 columns you need to have 3 properties to distinguish the data in the plot. This would be for example color, x-position and pointtype. What the script basically does:

1. Generates random data for testing (take your file instead)

`$Data` looks like this:

```
  8  64  57773  0
  4  32  64721  2
  8  32  56757  1
  4  16  56226  2
  8   8  56055  1
  8  64  59874  0
  8  32  58733  0
  4  16  55525  2
  8  32  58869  0
  8  64  64470  0
  4  32  60930  1
  8  64  57073  2
  ...
```

2. the variables  `ColX`, `ColC`, `ColP`, and `ColS` define which columns are taken for x-position, color, pointtype and statistics.
3. find unique values of `ColX`, `ColC`, `ColP`, (check `help smooth frequency`) and put them to datablocks `$ColX`, `$ColC`, and `$ColP`.
4. put the unique values to arrays `ArrX`, `ArrC`, `ArrP`
5. loop all possible combinations and do statistics on `ColS` and put it to `$Data2`. Add 3 columns at the beginning for color, x-position and pointtype.

`$Data2` looks like this:

```
  1  1  1  0  8  4  61639.4  2788.4
  1  1  2  0  8  8  59282.1  2740.2
  1  2  1  0 16  4  59372.3  2808.6
  1  2  2  0 16  8  60502.3  2825.0
  1  3  1  0 32  4  59850.7  2603.8
  1  3  2  0 32  8  60617.7  1979.8
  1  4  1  0 64  4  60399.4  3273.6
  1  4  2  0 64  8  59930.7  2919.8


  2  1  1  1  8  4  59172.6  2288.2
  2  1  2  1  8  8  58992.2  2888.0
  2  2  1  1 16  4  59350.1  2364.6
  2  2  2  1 16  8  61034.0  2368.5
  2  3  1  1 32  4  59920.8  2867.6
  2  3  2  1 32  8  59711.9  3464.2
  2  4  1  1 64  4  60936.7  3439.7
  2  4  2  1 64  8  61078.7  2349.3


  3  1  1  2  8  4  58976.0  2376.3
  3  1  2  2  8  8  61731.5  1635.7
  3  2  1  2 16  4  58276.0  2101.7
  3  2  2  2 16  8  58594.5  3358.5
  3  3  1  2 32  4  60471.5  3737.6
  3  3  2  2 32  8  59909.1  2024.0
  3  4  1  2 64  4  62044.2  1446.7
  3  4  2  2 64  8  60454.0  3215.1
```

6. Finally, plot the data. I couldn't figure out how plotting style `with yerror` works properly together with variable pointtypes. So, instead I split it into two plot commands `with vectors` and `with points`. The third one `keyentry` is just to get an empty line in the legend and the forth one is to get the pointtype into the legend.

I hope you can figure out all the other details and adapt it to your data.

**Code:**

```
### grouped statistics on filtered (unsorted) data 
reset session
set colorsequence classic

# generate some random test data
rand1(n) = 2**(int(rand(0)*2)+2)    # values 4,8
rand2(n) = 2**(int(rand(0)*4)+3)    # values 8,16,32,64
rand3(n) = int(rand(0)*10000)+55000 # values 55000 to 65000
rand4(n) = int(rand(0)*3)           # values 0,1,2
set print $Data
do for [i=1:200] {
    print sprintf("% 3d% 4d% 7d% 3d", rand1(0), rand2(0), rand3(0), rand4(0))
}
set print
print $Data    # (just for test purpose)

ColX = 2   # column for x
ColC = 4   # column for color
ColP = 1   # column for pointtype
ColS = 3   # column for statistics

# get unique values of the columns
set table $ColX
    plot $Data u (column(ColX)) smooth freq
unset table

set table $ColC
    plot $Data u (column(ColC)) smooth freq
unset table

set table $ColP
    plot $Data u (column(ColP)) smooth freq
unset table

# put unique values into arrays
set table $Dummy
    array ArrX[|$ColX|-6]   # gnuplot creates 6 extra lines
    array ArrC[|$ColC|-6]
    array ArrP[|$ColP|-6]
    plot $ColX u (ArrX[$0+1]=$1)
    plot $ColC u (ArrC[$0+1]=$1)
    plot $ColP u (ArrP[$0+1]=$1)
unset table
print ArrX, ArrC, ArrP    # just for test purpose

# define filter function
Filter(c,x,p) = ArrX[x]==column(ColX) && ArrC[c]==column(ColC) && \
               ArrP[p]==column(ColP) ? column(ColS) : NaN

# loop all values and do statistics, write data into $Data2
set print $Data2
    do for [c=1:|ArrC|] {
        do for [x=1:|ArrX|] {
            do for [p=1:|ArrP|] {
                undef var STATS*
                stats $Data u (Filter(c,x,p)) nooutput
                if (exists('STATS_mean') && exists('STATS_stddev')) {
                    print sprintf("% 3d% 3d% 3d% 3d% 3d% 3d% 9.1f % 7.1f", c, x, p, ArrC[c], ArrX[x], ArrP[p], STATS_mean, STATS_stddev)
                }
            }
        }
    print "";  print ""
    }  
set print
# print $Data2  # just for testing purpose

set xlabel sprintf("Column %d", ColX)
set ylabel sprintf("Column %d", ColS)
set xrange[0.5:|ArrX|+1]
set xtics ()    # remove all xtics
do for [x=1:|ArrX|] { set xtics add (sprintf("%d",ArrX[x]) x)}   # set xtics "manually"

# function for x position and offsets, 
# actually not dependent on 'n' but to shorten plot command
# columns in $Data2: 1=color, 2=x, 3=pointtype
width = 0.5   # float number!
step = width/(|ArrC|-1)
PosX(n) = column(2) - width/2.0 + step*(column(1)-1) + (column(3)-1)*step*0.3

plot \
     for [c=1:|ArrC|] $Data2 u (PosX(0)):($7-$8):(0):(2*$8) index c-1 w vectors \
     heads size 0.04,90 lw 2 lc c ti sprintf("%g",ArrC[c]),\
     for [c=1:|ArrC|] '' u (PosX(0)):7:($3*2+4):(c) index c-1 w p ps 1.5 pt var lc var not, \
     keyentry w p ps 0 ti "\n", \
     for [p=1:|ArrP|] '' u (0):(NaN) w p pt p*2+4 ps 1.5 lc rgb "black" ti sprintf("%g",ArrP[p])

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. One more question though. Any idea how to remove the "tab" after each value in the Label table so that I don't get a large whitespace between the value and the symbol in the legend?

Comment: Before the plot command you can add the line `set key Left` to get it a bit closer. Note: it is `Left` not `left`. See `help key`.

Comment: This does not do. It is the tab that creates a large whitespace after the letters, so even if I reverse the symbols and letters, the box will still be much larger than needed. The only solution is to remove the tabs from the values.

Comment: ok, I see... A quick fix would be replacing `$Label[i+1]` by `word($Label[i+1],1)`. I modified it in the code.

Comment: I am trying to edit your script but without any luck... I want to be able to add a fourth parameter, lets say the last column (here only 0, imagine that it can also take 1 and 2), according to which the column for the statistics is summed, eg sum the ColS for the same ColG, ColF and Col_NEW (and calcualte the error accordingly. Is this possible?

Comment: certainly somehow possible, haven't yet thought about it. So besides values in Col2 (4,8,...) you have Col3 (8,32,64,...) you have Col17 (0,1,2,...). How do you want to group, cluster, color and display the data?

Comment: Same as is now, just sum first all the ColSs that have the same ColF, ColG and Col_NEW.

Comment: I am still not able to calculate the sum of ColS for the values of ColC before I calculate the stats for it. Any idea?

Comment: Why do _you_ need to calculate the sum of `ColS`? The line `stats $Data u (Filter(c,x,p))` is doing this for you...

Comment: Yes, but it does not sum the ColS's for the various ColC. It splits them. I want them summed and not calculated for each value of ColC separately.
1  1  1  0  4 64   4440.0   198.7
2  1  1  1  4 64   1810.7    24.8
3  1  1  2  4 64   2063.6    32.8
I want the average of the sum for the 7th column here for the 0,1,2 and the stdev calculated accordingly.

Comment: now I'm confused. Are you talking about 2 versions? Version1: filtered by 2 columns with mean and stddev of ColS and Version2: filtered by 3 columns with sum of ColS?

Comment: Only one, an update to the original for special cases: the second that you mention, sum them the ColS by ColC for the various combinations of ColX and ColP.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think gnuplot can produce exactly what you are asking for in a single plot command.  I will show you two alternatives in the hope that one or both is a useful starting point.

**Alternative 1: standard boxplot**

```
spacing = 1.0
width = 0.25
unset key
set xlabel "Column 3"
set ylabel "Column 9"
plot 'data' using (spacing):9:(width):3 with boxplot lw 2
```

[image]

This collects points based on the value in column 3 and for each such value it produces a boxplot.  This is a widely used method of showing the distribution of point values in a category, but it is a quartile analysis not a display of mean + standard deviation.

**Alternative 2: calculate mean and standard deviation for categories known in advance**

The boxplot analysis has the advantage that you do not need to know in advance what values may be present in column 3.  Gnuplot *can* calculate mean and standard deviation based on a column 3 value, but you need to specify in advance what that value is.  Here is a set of commands tailored to the specific example file you provided.  It calculates, but does not plot, the requested categorical mean and standard deviation.  You can use these numbers to construct a plot, but that will require additional commands.  You could, for example, save the values for each category in a new file, or array, or datablock and then go back and plot these together.

```
col3entry = "8 32 64"
do for [i in col3entry] {
    stats "data" using ($3 == real(i) ? $9 : NaN) name "Condition".i nooutput
    print  i, ": ", value("Condition".i."_mean"), value("Condition".i."_stddev")

}
```

output:

```
8: 62345.1111111111 1259.34784220021
32: 63115.6 392.552977316438
64: 59809.6 881.583711283279
```